# Is it possible to save a reference to a not yet existing elment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom

I have attempted to asked this question before, but it's quite difficult to explain. So here I'm going to try to rephrase it.

This is my HTML body:

```
<bod>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
</body>
```

In JavaScript I'm calling a function with references to nodes as arguments. Some of them exists, some don't.

```
myElements([document.getElmentById('foo'), document.getElmentById('bar'), document.getElmentById('peaches'), document.getElmentById('oranges')]);
//foo and bar exist, peaches and oranges don't

function myElements(list){
window.list = list; //list returns [element], [element], null, null
}
```

The problem, that I'm having is that when I call the variable window.list **after** *peaches* and *oranges* have been created, that they are not referenced because they are null in window.list.
Is there any way I can save a reference to elements that have not yet been created. I **can't** use class, id, etc., because I am creating these elements dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add dynamically created elements when you create them?

Comment: What do you want to do with this list? If an element doesn't yet exist, it is not very usefull to have a reference to it.. If you want to use the element as soon as it exists you just call that `myElements`-function, right? Or make a timeout that checks once in a while whether the elements exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can save a reference to elements that have not yet been created.

No. But see below.

> I can't use class, id, etc., because I am creating these elements dynamically.

You *are* using `id`s.

The best thing to do is simply to have the code that creates the elements then call the function with the elements that have been created. Anything else is basically a workaround if for some reason you can't do that.

One such workaround is polling: You set up a timer to check back.

```
myElements(['foo', 'bar', 'peaches', 'oranges']);

function myElements(list){

    window.list = list;
    findElements();

    function findElements() {
        var n, element, entry, repeat = false;
        for (n = 0; n < window.list.length; ++n) {
            entry = window.list[n];
            if (typeof entry === "string") {
                element = document.getElementById(entry);
                if (element) {
                    window.list[n] = element;
                }
                else {
                    repeat = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (repeat) {
            setTimeout(findElements, 50); // Do it again, 50ms later
        }
    }
}
```

That will keep trying to find the elements until it's found them all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible explicitly the way you want it. To reference an object, you need it to exist.

However, if your goal is actually to reference an object that *isn't yet visible*, you can create these with

```
var htmlElement = document.createElement(elem);
```

without appending it to the DOM at that point. By that you get a reference to this. Then, when it actually needs to be visible, you just add it to the dom with

```
parent.appendChild(htmlElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference something that doesn't exist, because the reference doesn't exist yet.  So unless you can find some other way to identify these items (it looks like they have IDs, so I don't understand why you can't use them), you're out of luck.

Comment: It's just an example to make things easier. Actually I am *not* using ids.

Answer (score 0):

No it can't be done.

Why don't you select the elements later, when you're trying to use them?

Another approach would be to listen for document ready, (or simply putting your javascript at right before `</body>` and *then* select them.